# PHP: Check mysql database every 10 seconds for any new rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, database

I am making a php chat and am starting the php checking database part. So when a user types something into the chat, it gets recorded in the MySQL database, how would I check the database every 10 seconds so that one user's chat would update with new messages from other users. I know that you can use an ajax request to a page with an interval, but I want the php to be on the same page, instead of having to use numerous pages. This is the code for checking the database

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('host','user','pass','database');
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `messages`");
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
 $user = $row['user'];
 $message = $row['message'];
 echo 'User: ',$user,' Message: ',$message;
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance anyone!

Comment: we can call ajax to the same page also

Comment: I think that a crontask could be a solution

Comment: You could try XMPP for IM kind of application.  have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037062/how-to-develop-a-web-based-xmpp-chat-facility-using-php-and-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need. We need set time for ajax auto reload. Don't put everything in one page. Because you must reload page to refresh data. That is bad solution.

[Call jQuery Ajax Request Each X Minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930439/call-jquery-ajax-request-each-x-minutes)

Answer (score 1):

Use MySQL Event Scheduler.

Below link will guide you through .

http://www.9lessons.info/2012/10/mysql-event-scheduler.html.

I think best option in your case .

Comment: I think what he want is auto update data from database to browser. mysql scheduler can't do it.

Comment: Then using ajax is the option.

Comment: you use mysql scheduler for what? I think it used in case we want maintenance database system, example delete trash data.... In this case, if he ask he want to delete chat message over 7 days, we can use it.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is probably the simplest solution. You can perform an AJAX request on the same page your PHP code is executing on if you really want to.

```
(function check() {
    $.get('mypage.php', function(data) {
        doSomethingWith(data);
        setTimeout(check, 5000); // every 5 seconds
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't have a setInterval function. While I'm sure you can use a crontask to automate it on the server, you can also achieve this with some simple Javascript.

The concept you are trying to achieve is known as Short Polling. What you want to do is to have a `setInterval` function in Javascript that constantly makes AJAX requests to your PHP file which performs the check to the database for new messages. Your PHP should return that information to your script where you can then simply populate the user's screen.

There is also Long Polling where you simply maintain the connection and have a `setTimeout` to wait for messages to come in. You can find more information yourself and if you have questions, you can come back here.

A good video about this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHmSqFor1HU

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually with a help of a bit JS, SSE can be used.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Answer (score 0):

Make a while for 30 seconds, and check the db every second, once you find a record the while is being broken, also it is being broken when 30 secs are expired.

```
$sec = 1;
while($sec <= 30) {
   if(has record)
      Send to the user;
   $sec++;

   sleep(one sec here);
}
```

Use sleep for 10 secs in order to check every 10 secs...

Comment: wrong solution, server will lost 30 seconds to run this code.

Comment: That is true, but it was not about to find a solution, I just put a word, how is this possible to do with PHP as it was requested.